# How to customize CreateUserWizard to get UserId and UserName values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, profile, createuserwizard

I am using `Membership provider` to deal with *user* registration and logging to the website. This `Membership provider` is part of a package comes through:

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers

I have two `ASPX` pages one has a `CreateUserWizard` control and the other has a `Login` control. The registration and logging is working correctly.

I have defined `Profile` properties in the web.config file:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <properties>
    <add name="Id" type="System.Guid" />
    <add name="UserName"/>
  </properties>
```

What I am trying to is to be able to take the `UserId` and `UserName` values on registration of the user, and store them to `Profile.Id` and `Profile.UserName` respectively.

How to customize the `CreateUserWizard` to achieve this?.

**My try:**
When you show `CreateUserWizard` on the browser. You can see a button named "Create User", so I thought it is a good place to extend on and add code to take the required values. So I clicked the small arrow on `CreateUserWizard` and choose `Customize Create User Setup`, but the *editable template* doesn't include the corresponding button of "Create User".

So what is the possible way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the aspx file under events of the CreateUserWizard control, there is a "createdUser" event you can create.

In the cs file of the CreateUser function put in:

```
    MembershipUser newUser = Membership.GetUser(NewUserWizard.UserName);
    Guid newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

newUser.UserName will give you the UserName, and NewUserId will give you the id. At that point you should have what you need.

Comment: What are the required namespaces; I added `using System.Web.Security;` but an error says: `Membership doesn't contain a definition for 'GetUser'`.

Comment: `generate method stub for 'GetUser' in 'Membership`

Comment: You will need  System.Web.UI.WebControls, though for my uses, I use: using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;